# How to align items in a line across columns

Tags: javascript, css

Using flexbox this is what I have

```css
.flexer{
  display:flex;


  margin:1px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flexer .column{
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
h1.title{
  font-size: 2.0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexer">

<div class="column">

<h1 class="title">

Short 
</h1>
<p>

Body 1
</p>

</div>

<div class="column">


<h1 class="title">

Medium
</h1>
<p>

Body 2
</p>
</div>

<div class="column">

<h1 class="title">

Very very long title that ends up spanning multiple lines
</h1>
<p>

Body 3
</p>


</div>

<div class="column">

<h1 class="title">

Short 
</h1>
<p>

Body 4
</p>


</div>

</div>
```

[image]

Regardless of the title (since they're picked from database)
I want the body to start at the same across the columns

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add flex display to columns and justify the content with space-between:

```css
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```